# Centralizar ul dentro da div responsivo

Tags: css, css3, bootstrap-3

Tenho uma tela que será uma dashboard e nela tenho vários painéis que são li com float:left para que quando a tela for redimensionada vá passando os painéis para baixo ficando assim responsivo. Meu problema é que preciso deixar esses painéis centralizados na página e só consegui via javascript, tem como fazer somente com o uso do css? Abaixo segue uma imagem de como está hoje, observe que o mesmo não está centralizado, e se eu definir margens quando redimensiono a página fica toda errada.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: A largura destes "painéis" é fixa ou não?

Comment: Poderia utilizar largura percentual? 25% para cada uma?

Comment: tag <center></center> ?

Comment: A largura é fixa em 400px e quando for abaixo de 450px a tela ai fica em 100%

Comment: Poderia criar um arquivo no paint (ou outro) de como voce quer deixar? A minha sugestao seria semelhante a que foi sugerida pelo @Andre Monteiro

Answer (score 0):

Utilize um painel pai para resolver isso, e mude o painéis internos para display: inline-block;

```css
.painel{
  height:150px;
  width:220px;
  display:inline-block;
  background-color:#fff;
  margin:5px;
  
}
#painelPai{
    margin:auto;
    float: left;
    background-color: red;
    text-align:center;
    width:100%;
    
}
```

```html
<div id="painelPai">
  
    <div class="painel">Painel1</div>
    <div class="painel">Painel2</div>
    <div class="painel">Painel3</div>
    <div class="painel">Painel4</div>
    <div class="painel">Painel5</div>
    <div class="painel">Painel6</div>
    <div class="painel">Painel7</div>
    <div class="painel">Painel8</div>
  
</div>
```

Segue o exemplo: [Exemplo](https://jsfiddle.net/Ln6cmpup/6/)

Comment: Legal André, obrigado pela ajuda, mais eu já havia tentando dessa maneira, porém o designer não aceita que os boxes quebrem na última linha tem que ficar todos alinhados e somente a div do contorno seja centralizada, essa foi a maneira mais próxima que cheguei também; Conseguiu entender? No caso está perfeito está centralizando e responsivo, porém os boxes devem ficar alinhados um abaixo do outro, a solução que achei até o momento foi criar uma diretiva do angular para fazer isso pra mim, porém via css não consegui.